# Not able to disable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb

So I am trying to have the add contact button disabled if the user.id already exists in the friendRequest array. However, for some reason the code is not working the way it is suppose to, and nothing is being disabled. Please help.

File for route:

```
exports.addContact = function(req, res, err) {
    console.log('route add');
    User.findById(req.signedCookies.userid, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            if({ friendRequest: user.id,  $exists: true }) {
                return true;
                console.log('route add true');
            } else {
                res.send(err);
            }

        } 
    })
};

exports.addContactPost = function(req, res, err) {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.signedCookies.userid, {
                $push: {friendRequest: req.body.friendRequest}
            }, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log("post2");
                    console.log(err);
                    return console.log('error');
                    //return res.render('addContactError', {title: 'Weblio'}); 

                } 

                else {

                    console.log('postsuccess');
                    //alert('Contact added');
                    res.json({response: true});

                }

            });
};
```

File for Script:

```
 //see if friend exists if not friend request exist if not user sent request
    $('.addContact').ready(function() {
        $.get('/addContact',
            {friendRequest: $(this).data('user')});
        if($(this)===true) {

            return $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').html('Contact Requested');
        };
        console.log(this);
});

    //Add friends
    $('.addContact').click(function() {
        $.post('/addContact',
           {friendRequest: $(this).data('user')});

        if($(this).html!=='Contact Requested') {
            return $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').html('Contact Requested');
        }
        });
```

Jade file:

```
extends layout
block content   
    div
    legend Search Results
    div#userResults
    for user in ufirstName 
        a(href='/user/#{user.id}')
            p #{user.firstName} #{user.lastName}
        button.addContact(data-user=user.id) Add Contact
```

Currently the user gets added to the array and in my second script it turns the attribute of the button to disabled but I am not trying to do an ajax get to see if the user exists in the friendRequest array. The console.log('route add true') does not get called.

Comment: That `if ($(this) === true)` looks awful suspicious to me.  Is that the jQuery `$`? If so, that will **never** be `true`.

Comment: You should change the title of your question to be more specific to the problem.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're doing, but the `$.get()` and `$.post()` look wrong. Those are **asynchronous** calls, and the result will not be available in the code that immediately follows those calls.

Comment: Yeah, having a difficult time here. the $.post() works, but was trying to now check if the user already has a friend request pending and if so disable the button. I was not sure how to go about sending the get to check if the route returned true or not... but even the route file does not send true... so was looking to see if I should be changing things around and examples would be great... been trying to research it for a while but everything is using php

Comment: `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` is wrong. `disabled` is a property, not an attribute. you should be using `.prop` with `true` or `false`

Comment: You cannot return from the success or error callbacks of an ajax request such as $.get or $.post